# Set certain values in column B by matching it to another pair of columns

Tags: vba, excel

In First sheet I have many rows (but less than 10 thousand rows)

```
 A     B
198
198
198
197
197
225
…
…
…
119
229
```

In a Second sheet I have the matching values (some will be empty e.g 8.6 has no pair). Values in A are not sequential, while B is sequential from 0.1 to 21.1 (0.1 interval)

```
 A      B
139    0.1
211    0.2
208    0.3
208    0.3
207    0.4
…
…
…
229    4.0
…
…
…
119    7.4
…
…
…
-      8.6
198    8.5
197    8.7
…
…
…
225    9.9
```

After the macro/VBA I want the result in the First sheet, such as: (please can someone give me some hints, thank you very much)

```
 A     B
198   8.5
198   8.5
198   8.5
197   8.7
197   8.7
225   9.9
…
…
…
119   7.4
229   4.0
```

Comment: what "result" are you after? counts, sums, simple lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sheet, use a `VLOOKUP` function to find corresponding matches in the second sheet (I'll call that *Sheet2*. with `IFERROR` to catch no matches. In the first sheet's B2 cell, use this formula,

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, 'Sheet2'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), "")`

[VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010069835.aspx)

That will return the first value in column B that corresponds to a matching value in column A which seems to be what you want. Other options would be `SUMIF`, `AVERAGEIF` and/or `COUNTIF`.

Comment: Woow thank you very much - it works well. May I know what col_index_num i.e. the value "2" mean ? Is it making sure column 2 or B of sheet2 taken as the return value into column A in sheet1 ?

Comment: @bennyhardjono - Yes, that's it. `VLOOKUP` will always use the first column in *table_array* to lookup the values and return the corresponding value from column noted by *col_index_num*. If the *table_array* was `'Sheet2'!$A:$Z` and *col_index_num* was 13 then the value from column M would be returned when a match in column A was found. Always make sure that *col_index_num* does not exceed the number of columns in *table_array*.